# Why the inconsistent lines in C FAQ question 16.7?

Tags: c

C FAQ question 16.7: http://c-faq.com/strangeprob/ptralign.html

I have a question regarding the line:

```
s.i32 |= (unsigned)(*p++ << 8);
```

I understand how that line of code works, but I don't understand why it is not simply written as either:

```
s.i32 |= (long) *p++ << 8;
```

or:

```
s.i32 |= (unsigned)*p++ << 8;
```

Why is it this way?

===========================

```
struct mystruct {
    char c;
    long int i32;
    int i16;
} s;

char buf[7];
unsigned char *p;
fread(buf, 7, 1, fp);
p = buf;

s.c = *p++;

s.i32 = (long)*p++ << 24;
s.i32 |= (long)*p++ << 16;
s.i32 |= (unsigned)(*p++ << 8); // line in question
s.i32 |= *p++;

s.i16 = *p++ << 8;
s.i16 |= *p++;
```

============

**Update:**

It's still not clear to me why the casting must be done **after** the shift operation for the line in question. Maybe as littleadv said, "It's an example, not the only possibility".

If there is anything wrong with the two alternatives I proposed, please add your answer. For now I am choosing littleadv's comment as the answer, although the order of precedence for cast and << was not really what confused me.

P.S. I could not direct the question to the author of the FAQ because he is no longer accepting any questions by email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because casting is above `<<` in the [order of precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm), and you want the casting to be on the result of `<<`.

**edit for clarifications**

The reason the casting is done **before** shifting for `long`, and after shifting for `unsigned` is explained in a [different question with the same code](http://c-faq.com/stdio/extconform.html):

"This code assumes that getc reads 8-bit characters, and that the data is stored most significant byte first (``big endian''). The casts to (long) ensure that the 16- and 24-bit shifts operate on long values (see question 3.14), and the cast to (unsigned) guards against sign extension. (In general, it's safer to use all unsigned types when writing code like this, but see question 3.19.) ".

Comment: So why does the same rationale not apply to the two lines immediately preceeding?

Comment: what's wrong with casting *p++ to unsigned (int) before performing the shift operation?

Comment: I guess the question is: Why is it not done for the two lines with `<< 16` and `<< 24`

Comment: actually for that two lines, the casting must be done before the shift operation otherwise overflows may occur (if int is 16 bit).

Comment: @Nemo - "This code assumes that getc reads 8-bit characters, and that the data is stored most significant byte first (``big endian''). The casts to (long) ensure that the 16- and 24-bit shifts operate on long values (see question 3.14), and the cast to (unsigned) guards against sign extension. (In general, it's safer to use all unsigned types when writing code like this, but see question 3.19.) "  - http://c-faq.com/stdio/extconform.html

Comment: @littleadv: I cannot see what's wrong with the two alternatives I mentioned. Could you please be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: @Jeff, this is an example how unpacking should be done, I'm guessing they did it to show all the options, as they explain elsewhere.

Comment: @Vince - nothing, who said it's wrong? Nemo asked why the FAQ shows what it shows, and the FAQ explains it, as I quoted. It's an example, not the only possibility.

Comment: @littleadv: Thanks for the clarification. The intention of my question is find out why the code was written in that specific way. Since that line of code was obviously inconsistent with previous lines, I was just curious if the author was trying make a special point. I understand why the casting to unsigned is required, but I don't see why that order is necessary ((unsigned << int) is still unsigned after integral promotion, is it not?) or why not just use (long) (save memory?).

Comment: @Vince Hmmm. I actually think it is to make a special point. As to the order, I'm not sure I would do that the way they did in the example, I would go for the casting to `long` as wih the previous two cases. I think your question should be addressed to the writers of the FAQ. Technically there's nothing wrong with the way they did it, but in real life you would probably not do it that way. If you do cast to `int` (which is smaller than `long` in their example), you would probably need to cast the result, because the interim may be larger, as they did.

Comment: Oops, disregard my last comment.  I didn't realize you were quoting the page there.  Though what they say about the sign extension still doesn't make sense to me... it's a left shift.

Comment: @Jeff: Here is my understanding regarding the "guarding against sign extension": "*p++ << 8" results in (signed) int because of integral promtion (*p++ is unsigned char and 8 is int; unsigned char is promoted to int). The next operation "s.i32 |= (signed) int" will have a problem if the right operand is not casted to (unsigned), because when integral promotion promotes a negative int to long, it could change the bit pattern of the int. However, the casting to unsigned does not necessarily have to be done in that order, in my opinion.

Comment: @Vince: That clears things up thanks.  I've written plenty of C and when doing bit-manipulation, I've always restricted myself to using unsigned ints (or higher) and this never became an issue for me.